# lazyload.js and mCustomScrollbar

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, mcustomscrollbar

I am using a horizontal image viewer with lazyload.js and [mCustomScrollbar](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjWqOy2-K_LAhVEKGMKHZ3CCOQQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmanos.malihu.gr%2Fjquery-custom-content-scroller%2F&usg=AFQjCNG3SV8k77Dgh_pA8I24EzrC2vSgbA&bvm=bv.116274245,d.cGc)

I can get it to work however I do not think my code is sound and there is a lag when the pages loads before I can click, drag or scroll the slider.

[This post](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiznp3d-K_LAhUQ4WMKHYfnBPQQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F15532362%2Fjquery-custom-scrollbar-and-lazy-load&usg=AFQjCNG0WLIH8dgLm6lkArHnTWiaAxiBiQ&bvm=bv.116274245,d.cGc) was very helpful, but not 100% there. I believe every time I scroll the page the code is being re outputted?

I am using the following code for the lazy load:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload({
container: jQuery("#slider"),  
skip_invisible : false,
});
jQuery(window).resize();
  });
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery(window).resize();    
});
</script>
```

and this is the code for the custom scrollbar

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#slider").mCustomScrollbar({
axis:"x",
            scrollButtons:{
                enable:true
            },
scrollButtons:{ enable: true },
autoDraggerLength: false,
theme:"dark-thin",
mouseWheel:{ preventDefault: true },
mouseWheel:{ invert: true},
            callbacks:{
                whileScrolling:function(){ WhileScrolling(); } 
            }
        });
        function WhileScrolling(){
            $("img.lazy").lazyload();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use lazysizes instead of jquery lazyload and it should work automatically without any strange code. https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Comment: Nice plugin, but it ins't working automatically. The custom scroll bar won't load because the content in the slider window isn't fully loaded. Is there a way to load the spacing the images would take up but not the actual image?

Comment: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/#tip-specifying-image-dimensions-minimizing-reflows-and-avoiding-page-jumps